# PHP racing like condition on string conversion

Tags: php, datetime, race-condition

I am having a very weird problem.

When I run my piece of code, I get an error saying `$carDay->date` is not an object. but when I run it in debug mode, it works fine. So I assume it is kind of a racing condition.

$trip is an object from ORM database (MySQL) and getStart-> is just a getter that gets the starting date in this format "20120929T024754". I convert that string to a date and then do stuff with the date. But like I said when I run it without debugging the date doesn't seem to be converted in time when I want to access it. Does anyone have anyone Idea why or what I can do about it ?

```
 private function calculateIntLate($trip) {
    $carDay = $trip->getStart();
    $carDay_date = $this->convertStringToDateTime($carDay);

    $carDate = $carDay_date->date;
  }

  public function convertStringToDateTime($string) {
    //012345678901234 
    //20120929T024754
    $year = substr($string, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($string, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($string, 6, 2);
    $hour = substr($string, 9, 2);
    $minute = substr($string, 11, 2);
    $second = substr($string, 13, 2);
    $dateTime = new \DateTime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute . ':' . $second);
    return $dateTime;
  }
```

Comment: `var_dump($carDay);` And according to your code it's a string, not an object.

Comment: Are you even using threads with shared data? (I don't believe this can happen in PHP without you doing so deliberately.)

Comment: I am not using threads. that is the strange part. Can it have something to do whit lazy loading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the answer [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382).

Aparently you cant use the Datetime->date property

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
$carDate = $carDay_date->date;
```

not

```
$carDate = $carDay->date;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo when removing unnecessary code for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Nealv: `var_dump($carDay_date);`

Comment: + `var_dump($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute . ':' . $second);`